# Selenium IDE Firefox: how to find different divs with specific content?

Tags: selenium

I have a test case where I need to check if `follow feature` works correctly. It is quite tricky because in app there is three different types of accounts based on user's activity and it is reflected in site structure as you can see below.
There are three different types of elements:
`(...)/div[2]/a/span`,
`(...)div[2]/a` and
`(...)div/a`

The perfect situation would be if all elements could be tested in one scenario without stopping testcase.

How can I go through `div` or `div[2]` elements and finally find `/a` or `/a/span` elements?

Bigger example of code:

```
<td>//div[@id='main']/div[2]/ol/li[8]/div/div/div[2]/a/span</td>
<td>//div[@id='main']/div[2]/ol/li[9]/div/div/div[2]/a/span</td>
<td>//div[@id='main']/div[2]/ol/li[10]/div/div/div[2]/a</td>
<td>//div[@id='main']/div[2]/ol/li[11]/div/div/div/a</td>
<td>//div[@id='main']/div[2]/ol/li[12]/div/div/div[2]/a</td>
<td>//div[@id='main']/div[2]/ol/li[13]/div/div/div[2]/a</td>
<td>//div[@id='main']/div[2]/ol/li[14]/div/div/div[2]/a/span</td>
<td>//div[@id='main']/div[2]/ol/li[15]/div/div/div/a</td>
<td>//div[@id='main']/div[2]/ol/li[16]/div/div/div[2]/a/span</td>
```

Comment: Few moments ago I solved problem with `div[2]` elements. But still I'm struggling with distinguishing `/a` and `/a/span` at the end of each line.

Comment: OK, I've already solved whole problem. it works quite well with `<td>//div[@id='main']/div[2]/ol/li[39]/div/div/div/a/child::*</td>`